# Accessibility identifier to a table view section

Tags: ios6, ios-ui-automation, uiaccessibility

I am adding accessibility identifiers to all the elements inside my project so that I can use them when I write testing automation script. However I noticed that the under table view, I have table view section and under section I have table view cells.

I could add accessibility identifier to the tableview and the cells, but not to the table view section. I cannot see user defined runtime attributes section for it.

Has anybody came across the same scenario earlier? Could you guys through some light on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the answer I gave over here answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104579/set-accessibilityidentifier-on-custom-table-section-header-view-for-uiautomation/14105731#14105731

Comment: Attach a screen shot, XCode interface builder should be able to add User Defined Runtime Attributes to each element.